# Homeomorphism from ${\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}$ or $S^1$ to $C$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to show a homeomorphism from ${\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}$ or $S^1$ to $C=\{z\in{\mathbb C} | |z|=1\}$.
I thought I was understanding the definition of a homeomorphism and that I should think about  $f(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$.
But, I can't practically show that.

Comment: What properties do you have to verify in order to prove it is a homeomorphism?

Comment: How do you define $S^1$ to begin with? I'd define it as $C$.

Comment: Here is a possible outline to avoid showing continuous inverse.

Step 1: $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z \cong [0,1]/\sim$ where $1 \sim 0$.

Step 2: Define $f:[0,1] \to C$ by $f(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$. By the universal property of the quotient topology, this induces a map $\tilde{f}:[0,1]/{\sim} \to C$.

Step 3: $\tilde{f}$ is evidently surjective and injective. Since $[0,1]/\sim$ is compact and $C$ is Hausdorff, $\tilde{f}$ is a homeomorphism

Comment: @AndresMeija: One can bypass Step 1 and just work directly with the quotient topology on $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z = \mathbb R / \sim$ where $x \sim y$ iff $x = y+n$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

I claim $f:\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\to C=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\}:x\mapsto \cos(2\pi x)+\sin(2\pi x)i$ is a homomorphism.

What you have to check:

1. That $f$ is a bijection (and therefore $f^{-1}$ exists.)
2. $f$ is continuous.
3. $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: To be pedantic, your function is $[x] \rightarrow \text{cos}(2\pi x) + \text{sin}(2\pi x)$ (where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$), and we first need to check that it is well defined.

Comment: I would add to the comment of Richard Jensen by saying that this is not just a pedantic point, it is a central point of the proof, tied in with the universal property of quotient maps as suggested in the comment of @AndresMeija.

Comment: Here, $x$ is an equivalence class; this is just different notation. It makes sense to write $\cos(2\pi x)+\sin(2\pi x)i$ since these functions are uniquely determined modulo $\mathbb Z$

Comment: 1 is most difficult to show for me.

Comment: injectivity is obvious. For surjectivity, you can say $\cos x$ is continuous and that $\cos(0)=1$, $\cos(\pi)=-1$, so it takes all values from $-1$ to $1$. For each value of $\cos$, there are two possible values of $\sin$, but you can replace $x$ by $-x$ if necessary